# Timing for Qualtrics Blocks

Tags: qualtrics

Qualtrics can time pages with Timing questions and time surveys with the embedded data field Q_TotalDuration. Does anyone know of a way to time a block of a survey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an embedded variable, let's call it "sb1" equal to Q_TotalDuration just before the block in the survey flow:

```
sb1 = ${e://Field/Q_TotalDuration}
```

Then set an embedded variable, let's call it "tb1" equal to Q_TotalDuration - sb1 just after the block in the survey flow:

```
tb1 = $e{ e://Field/Q_TotalDuration - e://Field/sb1 }
```